# If the key is not named id_rsa it does not work

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh

I created a key to connect in SSH with a passphrase. I have named my key `id_rsa_admin`. When I log in, the following message is displayed `Permission denied (publickey).`

In the logs, I find that ssh looks for a file `id_rsa` and therefore does not find the right file.

I find that if the key is not named `id_rsa` it does not work.

How to connect in ssh ?

```
~/.ssh/id_rsa_admin

ssh admin@vps718449.ovh.net -p 9215
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[Arronical's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/860956/256317) is good for a one-time connection, but would be painful in the long term. In order to make `ssh` always use this key when connecting to this server, you can add this to your `~/.ssh/config` (or create it if it does not exist):

```
Host vps718449.ovh.net
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_admin
```

Then you can connect with just `ssh admin@vps718449.ovh.net -p 9215`. As an added bonus you can also configure the port:

```
Host vps718449.ovh.net
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_admin
    Port 9215
```

Then you can connect with just `ssh admin@vps718449.ovh.net`. Even further:

```
Host vps718449.ovh.net vps
     Hostname vps718449.ovh.net
     User admin
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_admin
     Port 9215
```

Then just `ssh vps` will work! Of course `vps` is just an example, you can use any other alias you want (for example if you have more than one VPS). See `man ssh_config` for a list of the options you can set there.

Comment: @fkraiem thank you. How to do with three keys ?

Comment: @Mathieu Why three keys? If it's for three different hosts, just add one entry for each host, each with the appropriate key.

Comment: @fkraiem I have 3 different keys on the same server but for 3 user

Comment: @Mathieu I can't confirm this right now, but I think just adding three `IdentityFile` lines in the `Host` section should work. Also, if you put a `User` line, that user will become the default when connecting to that host, but you can still override it with `@`.

Comment: @fkraiem Thank you so much. It works, but the following error is displayed "Agent admitted failure to sign using the key". I use "SSH_AUTH_SOCK=0
" to connect but it must be done at each restart. Is there any other greeting ?

Comment: @Mathieu Why are you setting `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to 0? Typically, it is the path to the SSH agent socket...

Comment: @fkraiem I opened a new question http://askubuntu.com/questions/861222/can-not-connect-to-a-vps-in-ssh-with-a-key

Answer (score 16):

You need to use the `-i` option to your ssh command using the path to your key. The modified command will be:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_admin admin@vps718449.ovh.net -p 9215
```

Comment: thank you. With your reply, the following error is displayed "ssh: Could not resolve hostname i: Name or service not known"

Comment: Putting `-i` before the hostname works too; I think @Mathieu simply forgot the hyphen. :p