# Can not connect to a VPS in SSH with a key?

Tags: 16.04, ssh

When I connect to my VPS (16.04) with SSH, the connection is denied and the following error is displayed :

```
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

To connect, I have to enter the following command to make it work (my computer is on ubuntu 15.04) :

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=0
```

How do I not enter this command each time ? Is there a patch ?

Comment: Please use ```ssh -vvv yourIPserver``` will display more info to debug. <br/>
Anyway, remember ```chmod``` your ```.ssh``` folder to ```700``` and private key(ex:```id_rsa```) to ```600```

Comment: It's the first time I hear about this issue... Google yields some interesting things, such as this one: https://chrisjean.com/ubuntu-ssh-fix-for-agent-admitted-failure-to-sign-using-the-key/

Comment: And by the way, 15.04 is EOL, so questions regarding it are off topic.

Comment: Wait, this qurstion is tagged 16.04, so which one is it?

Comment: The rights to folders and files are correct. I have updated the question.

Comment: @Mathieu As your logs, you should check authorized_keys file in your server, chmod 600 as well. Btw, try again with ```ssh username@FQDNdomainonyourserver -p serverport```
Ex: ```ssh root@vps308496.ovh.net -p sshserverport```

Comment: The chmod is already at 600

Comment: @fkraiem 15.04 client, 16.04 server according to the post. Regardless the problem is client side so you are correct in your off-topic assessment

Answer (score 1):

You are using `ssh-agent` (or some derivative like `gnome-keyring`), which is storing your ssh keys. They might got removed, modified or somehow inaccessible during the time.

- check what keys are in `ssh-agent` using `ssh-add -l`. Do they exists?
- are you using `gnome-keyring`? How does your `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` look like? See `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK`. Then open "Passwords and keys" application and check the keys there (and remove the problematic ones).
- restart should take care of this problem too.